# using md-autocomplete from Angular Material in a ui-bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-material

**Problem**

Been trying to get the autocomplete dropdown to show, the `md-virtual-repeat-container` is ending up behind the modal, and I've tried playing with the z-index to get it above the modal with no luck. anyone know how to make something on the body appear above the modal?

**Solution**

So I found with CSS I can display the autocomplete dropdown using this code

```
md-virtual-repeat-container{
  z-index:10000 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

you might need to change your z-index but this worked for me